# Dynamic browsing using python (Mechanize, Beautifulsoup...)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, frame, mechanize

I am currently writing a python's parser for extract automatically some information from a website. I am using mechanize to browse the website. I obtain the following html code:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   XXXXX
  </title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8; no-cache;" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/rr/style_other.css" type="text/css" />
 </head>
 <frameset cols="*,370" border="1">
  <frame src="affiche_cp.php?uid=yyyyyyy&amp;type=entree" name="cdrg" />
  <frame src="affiche_bp.php?uid=yyyyyyy&amp;type=entree" name="cdrd" />
 </frameset>
</html>
```

I want to access to the both frames:

- in `cdrd` I must fill some forms and submit
- in `cdrg` I will obtain the result of the submission

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of my issue was to load the first frame and fill the form in this page. Then I load the second frame and I can read it and obtain the results associated to the form in the first frame.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I do not use `BeautifulSoup` for parsing HTML. But instead I use [PyQuery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery), which is similar but I like the CSS selector syntax as opposed to XPath. I also use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to make HTTP requests.

That alone is enough to scrape data, and submit requests. It can do what you want. I understand this probably isn't the answer you're looking for but it might very well be useful to you.

**Scraping Frames with PyQuery**

```
import requests
import pyquery

response = requests.get('http://example.com')
dom = pyquery.PyQuery(response.text)
frames = dom('frame')

frame_one = frames[0]
frame_two = frames[1]
```

**Making HTTP Requests**

```
import requests

response = requests.post('http://example.com/signup', data={
    'username': 'someuser',
    'password': 'secret'
})

response_text = response.text
```

`data` is a dictionary with the `POST` data to submit to the forms. You should use Chrome's network explorer, Fiddlr or Burp Suite to monitor requests. Whilst monitoring manually submit both forms. Inspect the HTTP requests and recreate the request using `Requests`.

Hope that helps a little. I work in this field, so if you require any more information feel free to hit me up.